# How can I insert a clickable submenu to explorer?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-shell

I want to collapse the open button with the open with submenu. That way when you mouse over 'open' the apps open on the right (like when you hover on 'open with') but you can click on 'open' to use the default application. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  i asked [the same question yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331180/how-can-i-make-a-cmenu-trackpopupmenu-submenu-menu-item-clickable) but just found yours...

Comment: @mark I gave you the only answer that I found.