# How can I make a CMenu TrackPopupMenu SubMenu menu-item clickable?

Tags: windows, mfc

Normally when you hover over a sub-menu (with the little arrow) on a CMenu menu item it delays briefly then shows the sub-menu items.  Also, if you click the item before the delay timeout, it shows the sub menu items.  I want the delay behavior, but I want a different behavior for the click.  That is, I want the sub-menu itself (the one with the arrow) to be a clickable entity too, i.e. it has an ID and results in a WM_COMMAND and menu dismissal.

The idea is, the main sub-menu menu item is a "default", and the sub-menu items are modified versions, e.g. "print->" (defaulting to default printer), and sub-menu items like "print preview" "print to file" etc.  Thanks for thoughts/suggestions.

**edit**:

```
IDR_MY_MENU MENUEX
BEGIN
    POPUP "menu"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "&Something Else", ID_MENU_SOMETHING_ELSE
        POPUP "&Print", ID_MENU_PRINT
           BEGIN
           MENUITEM "Print Pre&view", ID_MENU_PRINT_PREVIEW
           MENUITEM "Print to &File", ID_MENU_PRINT_TO_FILE
           END
        MENUITEM "", -1, MFT_SEPARATOR
        MENUITEM "&Bottom", ID_MENU_BOTTOM
        MENUITEM "&Done", ID_MENU_DONE
    END
END
```

Comment: I don't know that you'll be able to do this with a CMenu object.  But, you should be able to simulate the same thing with a thin border dialog.  I think  the BCG toolkit does something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if theres a better way as I last did this 2 years ago, but the way I solved the problem had one constraint: that you own the whole menu. If you do own the whole menu what you can do is create two columns (two columns in the menu/submenu that is, not a new submenu) and use the right column as a submenu and the left column as the default.

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks.  I think I've largely handled it via regular sub-menus and a mouse hook now... a little awkward and need to test on other OS versions but it seems to be working fine... Ill add that as an answer as well

Answer (score 0):

For future StackOverflowers, here's what I did...

1. Added a handler for `OnInitMenuPopup` and corresponding
   `ON_WM_INITMENUPOPUP()`, although doing this messed up my `UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` handler but I was able to resolve that by moving that code into the `OnInitMenuPopup` handler.
2. In the `OnInitMenuPopup` handler, set a hook for the mouse `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE,...)` (checking if one isn't already set because sub-menus can cause multiple calls)... and for each menu that initializes during the hook, push the `HMENU` onto a linked list.
3. In the mouse hook proc, checking the end of the list and working toward the front, verify each `HMENU` is still and active menu via `IsMenu` and remove it if it isn't.  If there are no menus left, `UnhookWindowsHook`.
4. If there are menus left in the hook proc, check for `WM_LBUTTONUP` or `WM_RBUTTONUP` and see if happened over one of your menu items (because of coordinate mapping of screen versus sub-menu that I couldn't figure out I ended up simply cycling through the menu items via `GetMenuItemRect` and checking `PtInRect` to determine this).
5. If there is a click hit, do `GetMenuItemInfo` on the item, and if there's a `hSubMenu` for that item and it has an `wID` (and the `wID` doesn't match the sub-menu handle), simply post the id as a `WM_COMMAND`, post a `WM_CANCELMODE` to dismiss the menu, and disable the hook... Bingo!

So, seems to work fine and everything else functions like normal.  The only issue at this point is a keyboard handler for selecting the item instead opening the sub-menu but I suspect the same idea works there as well.

Also, I added the main sub-menu text as the first item in the sub-menu list with a separator which added some clarity to what the menu was doing.